# Select the same fields in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a table that contains `sender | message | sent_to` 
and PHP page that shows the messages

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `msg`");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$msg = $info['message'];
echo "</br> $msg";
}
```

it shows all messages in the table that's ok, but I want to show the message where the sender is the same sender.
I hope to find a way to do that! 
Thank You :)

Comment: Add a `WHERE sender = 'something'` clause...?!

Comment: Where the sender is the sender? Do you mean where the sender is a certain person? Then use " where sender = Xxx" and change Xxx to the senderid/name/whatever you save in that coloum

Comment: Ok but I need a way without choose the sender?

Comment: That does not make sense. What do you expect the result to be if you don't choose a sender?

Comment: Are you trying to group the senders together? Perhaps you could add ORDER BY sender?

Comment: @JeremyGallant   that's great!! but the last question is how to separate them. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `msg` ORDER BY sender");
$sender = null;

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $msgSender = $info['sender'];

    if (isnull($sender) || $sender !== $msgSender)
    {
        echo "Messages for " . $msgSender;
        $sender = $msgSender;
    }

    echo "</br> $info['message']";
}
```

Comment: That exactly what I need, but there is a problem, Its repeating Message for, But I want Message for Mark in one list not repeating Message For. Really Thank You! @Jeremy Gallant

Answer (score 0):

First just choose the same sender

```
$id = 1;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `msg` WHERE `sender` = '{$id}'");
```

Then if sender, message and sent_to are all fields in the database then just do this

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $info['sender'] . " " . $info['message'] . " " . $info['sent_to'] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: That's Great but is there is a way without choose the sender? @32423hjh32423

Answer (score 0):

```
$sender_id = 123;
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `msg` WHERE `sender` = '{$sender_id}'");
```

Comment: That's Great but is there is a way without choose the sender? @Chen Asraf

Comment: It was just an example, you can set sender to whatever you want - be it the user ID of the current logged in user, or of a value in the database... etc